# In matplotlib, how to add plot() or scatter() to axes without adjusting x/y axis limits?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, axis, axes

In matplotlib, I have an Axes object `ax` that already has some lines plotted. Now I want to add a new line (`ax.plot()`) and some scatter points (`ax.scatter()`) without allowing those new operations to automatically adjust the existing x/y axis limits. In other words, if the new operations end up drawing outside of the existing x/y axis limits, so be it. The parts outside of the existing limits will simply not be seen. That's the desired result. How to do that in the cleanest way? Thanks.

(I know I can save all of the original limits to vars, and then run the new operations, and then set all of the original limits again. But I'm guessing there's an easier way.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks I found the answer myself: running `ax.autoscale(False)` will turn off auto adjustment of axis limits, then I can run the new operations I want.